# Sort numbers with slashes in knockout js or javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I have series of numbers as strings I want to sort.

for example 
`4604158/1/7,4604181/1/2,4604158/1/8,4604182/1/2,4604181/1/3, 4604282/1/2 etc.`

how can I achieve this with knockout js or even with simple javascript?

I am able to sort only numbers (without slashes) with the following code :

```
myObservableArray.sort(function (item1, piece2) {
    return item1.stringWithSlashes < item2.stringWithSlashes ? -1 : (item1.stringWithSlashes > item2.stringWithSlashes ? 1 : 0);
});
```

Comment: There is a column of a table I want to sort. The column contains numbers with slashes.

Comment: If there aren't too many digits to fit into a double float, you could convert to number via `+"1234/5/6".split("/").join("")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the strings and sort then with the first part, then the second and if equal by the third part.

```js
var array = ['4604158/1/7', '4604181/1/2', '4604158/1/8', '4604182/1/2', '4604181/1/3', '4604282/1/2'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.split('/'),
        bb = b.split('/');
    return aa[0] - bb[0] || aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[2] - bb[2];
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks, btw, I got it working with knockout js by following code :

   
`myObservableArray.sort(function (item1, item2) {

                    var aa = item1.split('/');
                    var bb = item2.split('/');

                    var firstNumber = aa[0] < bb[0] ? -1 : (aa[0] > bb[0] ? 1 : 0);
                    var secondNumber = aa[1] < bb[1] ? -1 : (aa[1] > bb[1] ? 1 : 0);
                    var thirdNumber = aa[2] < bb[2] ? -1 : (aa[2] > bb[2] ? 1 : 0);

                    return firstNumber || secondNumber || thirdNumber;
                });`

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic way to check with any separator and any length of separated result array.

```js
var array = ['4604158/1/7', '4604181/1/2', '4604158/1/8', '4604182/1/2', '4604181/1/3', '4604282/1/2'];
var separator = '/';

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  b = b.split(separator);
  return a.split(separator)
    .some((v, i) => (+v > +b[i]));
})

console.log(array);
```